# using stack build --ghc-opitions "-fPIC" to produce pie code

Tags: haskell-stack

if i invoke stack build with

```
stack build --ghc-options "-fPIC"
```

the resulting code ends up in the `../x86_64-linux-nopie` directory (and i assume it is not PIC). what am i doing wrong or is this a bug?

there is very little information on PIC, nopie (no-pie) on the web. is there a `-fnoPIC` flag for ghc? or how to achieve the same effect? is there somewhere information about stack using either the linux or the linux-nopie subdirectories?

my IDE (leksah or atom) produces by default its code in `x86_64-linux` and i would like invoke stack build to use the same directory. this should be achived by `-fPIC`.

i have stack 1.3.2 hpack-0.15.0 on a 64 bit debian stretch.

thank you for help!